# Google Analytics not loading in Macbook

Tags: macos, google-analytics, analytics

When I try to login to Google Analytics from MAC, the page doesn't load. It is showing a blank page. When I open the Analytics same account on another desktop (DELL, HP) it is opening fine.

[image: Google Analytics]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It could be your adblock or your browser or if have activated JavaScript or not.

- Have you try to access the website from an other browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera, ...) ?
- Have you try to deactivate Adblock and reload the page ? Once it happens to me, because the add-on was updated and I could not reach analytics.google.com anymore.

Javascript also must be activated on your browser to make it work.

Have a nice day

A.

Comment: I have tried to remove the Ablocker from Safari and Chrome but it was not working. 

No other browser is supporting. 

The javascript is already activated in my browser.

Comment: Do you use a VPN or special DNS? may be it could also be a some proxies configuration.

Comment: No I dont use VPN or any proxies